# Adding my middle name to a flight bought through a travel agent

Tags: airlines, emirates, travel-agents, malaysia-airlines

When I filled out the flight form, I forgot to add my middle to the last name (both are written in my passport.)

I paid double for the premium service package at checkout with lastminute.com. The travel agent said I can modify the date, name or passenger for no cost at all. But when I ask to have it modified, they refused to do so.

It's been half a month now that I've been trying to get it modified. My flight will be in October.

The only answer they give is they can't do it. The airline says they can't do it because the ticket is fully owned by the travel agent.

Does anyone know what I can do now? The travel agent doesn't want to help at all, even though I said I am willing to pay extra to have it modified.

Comment: AFAIK, your only option is the airline itself, not the travel agency. Changing the name of the passenger is usually an authority that only certain people have, it is not something anyone can do easily. Changing passport number or birthdate is something easy.

Comment: I did ask airlines they can't, only travel agent can do it. Then the travel agent said can't, they said airlines refused them to do it coz of airlines policy. As far as i call airlines so many times, they never received any request changes, as the travel agent only can modify it. They said the ticket is fully owned by travel agent. They can't do anything. Just to add my middle name why it's so hard not changing person, as i been charged double from the service package by the travel agent.

Comment: IIRC if passenger name changes are allowed at all, it is usually only for a very limited time, eg within 24 or 48 hours of booking. What do your booking T&C say? And sorry, but how did you *forget* to put the right information? Middle names often don’t matter but first and last names are essential, travel agents / airlines usually take care to point this out *in writing* when reservations are made.

Comment: Which airline? Lastminute.com FAQs says “Depending on the tariff you have purchased, you can modify your booking: correct the name of the passenger or change the route or dates of your flight. Please bear in mind that all changes are subject to the terms and conditions (T&Cs) of the airline: if the changes you would like to make are not included in the T&Cs of the airline, you will not be able to make these changes.” https://www.lastminute.com/en/help/assistance.html

Comment: It is our airlines in my country, they have a strict policy about name. It has to be exact the same what written in your passport. With international flight, it might be no issue.  First and surname only. If i check in and board, my local airlines have this strict policy about names. It need to be name, middle and surname. So what i have to do before is put my name and (middle name+surname) as long as it can be seen in the ticket

Comment: @KiuttyK It’s not just airlines in your country. **All** airlines have a strict passenger name policy. It’s usually extremely obvious what names are required in the online booking process, for phone bookings agents will ask for the required information. Hard to see how anyone can make a mistake with the entire name, not just a typo

Comment: I buy premium service package and has been charged double for it at checkout. Its include modify name, change passanger, route and date.

Comment: Emirates Airlines. When i buy the tickets, in the form its only ask NAME and surname so i put my name and surname only (without my middle name+surname)

Comment: I realized my mistakes less than an hour after buying it. Quicky i call them to modify they said they will and after i wait few hours, they emailed me say they can't coz airlines have strict policy. Then i tell them i want to cancel the flight and get refund. The guy said i can request full refund within 14 hours. When i said i want to get full refund, sudden immediately he said he can help to modify. So i trust him. After 3 days i get another email said they cant change it with same reason. And now i missed my 14 hours full refund, only can get tax refund

Comment: As a Malaysian, with our local flights we need to add middle name to surname. I only put name and surname (without middle+surname).

Comment: The airlines included is Malaysian Airlines and Emirates, international flight KCH-KUL-Manchester with return booked through the travel agent

Comment: I suggest adding this info (country, airline, and route) to your question, maybe someone with local experience will be able to provide an answer.

Comment: Each airline will have its own Terms & Conditions of Carriage. One (or both) of the T&Cs can affect what choices are available.

Comment: Doesnt help you out, but Ive found Emirates to be one of the helpful airlines Ive ever dealt with - I have a flight booked (directly) with them for September and, having just checked, can amend all the passenger details just fine.  So it looks like its a limitation of the agreement your travel agency has with the airline - these can differ massively from the T&Cs you have directly with the airline, as you are technically the agencies customer and not the airlines.